# Extracting binary data from a mixed data file

Tags: r

I am trying to read binary data from a mixed data file (ascii and binary) using R, the data file is constructed in a pseudo-xml format. The idea I had was to use the scan function, read the specific lines and then convert the binary to numerical values but I can't seem to do this in R. I have a python script that does this, but I would like to do the job in R, the python script is below. The binary section within the data file is enclosed by the start and end tags  and .

The data file is a proprietary format containing spectroscopic data, a link to an example data file is included below. To quote the user manual:

> Data of BinData elements are written as a binary array of bytes. Each
>   8 bytes of the binary array represent a one double-precision
>   floating-point value. Therefore the size of the binary array is
>   NumberOfPoints * 8 bytes. For two-dimensional arrays, data layout
>   follows row-major form used by SafeArrays. This means that moving to
>   next array element increments the last index. For example, if a
>   two-dimensional array (e.g. Data(i,j)) is written in such
>   one-dimensional binary byte array form, moving to the next 8 byte
>   element of the binary array increments last index of the original
>   two-dimensional array (i.e. Data(i,j+1)). After the last element of
>   the binary array the combination of carriage return and linefeed
>   characters (ANSI characters 13 and 10) is written.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance!

Link to example data file:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5F27d7b1eMfQWg0QVRHUWUwdk0/edit?usp=sharing

Python script:

```
import sys, struct, csv
f=open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
#
t = f.read()
i = t.find("<BinData>") + len("<BinData>") + 2 # add \r\n line end
header = t[:i]
#
t = t[i:]
i = t.find("\r\n</BinData>")
bin = t[:i]
#
doubles=[]
for i in range(len(bin)/8):
  doubles.append(struct.unpack('d', bin[i*8:(i+1)*8])[0])
#
footer = t[i+2:]
#
myfile = open("output.csv", 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerow(doubles)
```

Comment: what happens if the binary data happens to randomly contain the termination string `</BinData?>` ??  - Binary data in XML files should be base64 encoded or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the [pack package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pack) to make this easier.  You still have to search for the start/end of the binary data though.

```
b <- readBin("120713b01.ols", "raw", 4000)
# raw version of the start of the BinData tag
beg.raw <- charToRaw("<BinData>\r\n")
# only take first match, in case binary data randomly contains "<BinData>\r\n"
beg.loc <- grepRaw(beg.raw,b,fixed=TRUE)[1] + length(beg.raw)
# convert header to text
header <- scan(text=rawToChar(b[1:beg.loc]),what="",sep="\n")
# search for "<Number of Points"> tags and calculate total number of points
numPts <- prod(as.numeric(header[grep("<Number of Points>",header)+1]))

library(pack)
Data <- unlist(unpack(rep("d", numPts), b[beg.loc:length(b)]))
```